# Error "! Undefined control sequence." while adding images

Tags: captions

I am adding a lots of images around 100 of them. So, I am adding them like this:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                                
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]                                                                                                                     
\ContinuedFloat 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_PtBalance_type0.pdf}%
\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj2_phi.pdf}
\caption{control plots 18}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For first patch I did not added `\ContinuedFloat` after that for each patch I added the `\ContinuedFloat`. It was working fine till 17 similar patches above (i.e. 34 images). As soon as I added 18th patch to include two more image I am getting error below but I am unable to understand whats happening. When I googled it showed that it happens because `ContinuedFloat` assumes caption and I added in all of them even then its not working.

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.147 \begin{figure}[ht!]

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\@xfloat ...@fltovf \fi \global \setbox \@currbox 
                                                  \color@vbox \normalcolor \...
l.147 \begin{figure}[ht!]

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \color@vbox 
l.147 \begin{figure}[ht!]

? 

<Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarCon
trolRegion_CHS_PtBalance_type0.pdf, id=43, 569.12625pt x 552.0625pt>
<use Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBa
rControlRegion_CHS_PtBalance_type0.pdf>
<Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarCon
trolRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj2_phi.pdf, id=44, 569.12625pt x 552.0625pt>
<use Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBa
rControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj2_phi.pdf>
! Undefined control sequence.
\@largefloatcheck ->\ifdim \ht \@currbox 
                                         >\textheight \@tempdima -\textheigh...
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   >
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@currbox 

l.153 \end{figure}

? 
! Argument of \@xnext has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
Runaway argument?
\@currbox \@currlist \ifnum \count \@currbox >\z@ \advance \@pageht \@pagedp \E
TC.
! Paragraph ended before \@xnext was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
! Extra \else.
\end@float ...pdima \penalty \@floatpenalty \else 
                                                  \vadjust {\penalty -\@Miv ...
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
! You can't use `\vadjust' in vertical mode.
\end@float ...nalty \@floatpenalty \else \vadjust 
                                                  {\penalty -\@Miv \vbox {}\...
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
! Argument of \@xnext has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
Runaway argument?
\@currbox \@currlist \ifnum \count \@currbox >\z@ \advance \@pageht \@pagedp \E
TC.
! Paragraph ended before \@xnext was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.153 \end{figure}

? 
[2 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTB
arControlRegion_CHS_nBTagJet_medium.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/C
ontrolPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegi
on_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj2_pt.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlo
ts/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_AK
8_mass_so.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_
08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_v_mt.pdf, page is r
otated 90 degrees>]

! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.663     \end{document}

? 
[3 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTB
arControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj2_q.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plot
s/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlR
egion_CHS_ZeppenfeldWH_new.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlo
ts/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_AK
8_mass_pr.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_
08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj2_et
a.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees>] [4 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_0
1h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_phi_type0.pdf, page is 
rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoosted
ElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_vbf_maxpt_j2_pt.pdf, page is rotated 90 de
grees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV
_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_deltaphi_metak8jet.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./
Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarCont
rolRegion_CHS_costheta1_type0.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees>] [5 <./Plots/Con
trolPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion
_CHS_vbf_maxpt_jj_m.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTba
r/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_lepton_e.
pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/D
ibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj1_q.pdf, page 
is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoos
tedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_Puppi_AK8_jet_tau2tau1.pdf, page is rot
ated 90 degrees>] [6 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBooste
dElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_ZeppenfeldWL_type0_new.pdf, page is rotat
ed 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuC
uts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_nBTagJet_loose.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees>
 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBar
ControlRegion_CHS_ungroomed_PuppiAK8_jet_phi.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <
./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarCo
ntrolRegion_CHS_TempWWRapidity.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees>] [7 <./Plots/Co
ntrolPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegio
n_CHS_phi1_type0.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2
017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_ZeppenfeldWH
.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/
DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj1_eta.pdf, pa
ge is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonB
oostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_lepton_eta.pdf, page is rotated 90 d
egrees>] [8 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts
13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj1_m.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees
> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBa
rControlRegion_CHS_costheta2_type0.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/Co
ntrolPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegio
n_CHS_BDT_response.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar
/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_v_pt.pdf, 
page is rotated 90 degrees>] [9 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/Di
bosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_vbf_maxpt_j1_pt.pdf, page is r
otated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedE
lMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_VBSCentrality_type0.pdf, page is rotated 90
 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13
TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_vbf_maxpt_j2_eta.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <.
/Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarCon
trolRegion_CHS_ungroomed_PuppiAK8_jet_pt.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees>]
[10 <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TT
BarControlRegion_CHS_ZeppenfeldWL_type0.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plo
ts/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControl
Region_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj1_pt.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/Contro
lPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CH
S_nu_pz_type0.pdf, page is rotated 90 degrees> <./Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017
_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_AK8_mass_tr.pdf
, page is rotated 90 degrees>] (./DataTex.aux) )
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 153 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 153 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 153 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 153 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 153 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 153 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 153 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 153 was incomplete)</usr/share/texmf/fonts/t
ype1/bluesky/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/bluesky/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on DataTex.pdf (10 pages, 1113553 bytes).
```

Comment: you have given very few clues but the fact that you get an error around the 18th float suggests an old version of latex, is the error you show the first error, did you not get a "no room for a new float" error first?

Comment: please make a test document that shows the error otherwise it is virtually impossible to guess what you did or what is wrong. in your test file use `\rule{2cm}{2cm}` or something similar rather than `\includegraphics` that way the test does not need any external images,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : No I did not get "no room for a new float". Error starts with "! LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats." Now, I updated my question with more information. Please look at qestion again. May be now you can suggest me something.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: After adding several `\clearpage` after 2 or 3 blocks of `\begin{figure}` it goes. But, is there any other nicer way without adding manually the `clearpage`? Becaue I would like all the 100s of image placed together one after another.

Comment: sorry I mistyped the message. Yes that is the error. You should have shown that error in your question! Almost all errors after that are completely spurious, latex can not really recover from the first error in that case so you may as well just stop there. As I said I would be very surprised if you get that error with a current latex, you must have an old version (older than 2015 release) ?

Comment: using `[h]` makes this error quite likely in old latex releases, you should use something that allows the floats to be placed on a page, say `[!htp]`

Comment: your edit did not add any extra information, ideally you should provide a test file, also you should always show the _first_ error in your document (later errors are usually meaningless) and show what version of latex you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @David it was the issue with the older version of latex. But, for some reason I can't update. But the issue was fixed by using `\begin{tabular}` instead of `\ContinuedFloat`. Like below:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp] 
     \centering 
     \begin{tabular}{cc}
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_vbf_maxpt_jj_m.pdf}
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_lepton_e.pdf}\\
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_PuppiAK8_jet_sj1_q.pdf}
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_Puppi_AK8_jet_tau2tau1.pdf}\\
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_ZeppenfeldWL_type0_new.pdf}
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Plots/ControlPlots/TTbar/2017_12_08_01h14/DibosonBoostedElMuCuts13TeV_TTBarControlRegion_CHS_nBTagJet_loose.pdf}
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{Comparison plots between data and MC for different observables. From top to bottom:}
     \label{fig:CR_1}
\end{figure}
```